# How to get platform specific info for shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, python, language-agnostic, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

How can I get platform specific shortcut, or key binding for a specific process?

As an example how can I get the information that on *Windows* shortcut for *copying* is  <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> ? (I'd like the information on all of the tagged languages if possible) I mean both text editing and file manager usage, and also would like to know if they're independent.

Comment: Isn't `Ctrl + C` universal???

Comment: I really doubt there is an general answer to your question except "you can't".

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir:  no, its not universal.  Just look at arch-enemies `vi(1)` and `emacs(1)`.

Comment: @cdarke Given that and the fact there is `vi` for windows... The question is becoming meaningless as there is no "Windows shortcut for copying".

Comment: Do you maybe mean file manager shortcuts (Windows Explorer, Nautilus etc.)

Comment: Each application defines its own shortcuts for text editing, it's not an OS setting. As for file managers, you're pretty safe going with the standard Explorer shortcuts (`Ctrl + C` and such) as the others are based on it. Then you can have an "exceptions" list to handle any you may come across that do not behave like Explorer.

Comment: You also ask for *information on all of the tagged languages*.  Just as @mnistic says for the OS, key bindings have nothing to do with the programming language used to write an application.  There might be a default for GUI packages (Qt, Gdk, .Net), but they can usually be redefined by the app.

Comment: No, @ibrahim mahrir, ctrl-C for copy isn't universal. On macOS, copy is done with ⌘-C. That's the same for most macOS shortcuts - the command key (⌘) replaces the ctrl key. As a browser MouseEvent, pressing ⌘ is determined by checking `evt.metaKey`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you want rewrite system command of browser. In browser all process  start after some event.  You can copy text , if you use command for copy: `document.execCommand('copy')`; and you can rewrite all events except `paste`.
Example:

```
 document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
        if(ev.keyCode === 67 && ev.ctrlKey === true) { // ctrl+c
          console.log(ev);
         ev.preventDefault();//block default action of browser
        }
    });
```

and  trigger copy:

```
 document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => { //ctrl+z
        if(ev.keyCode === 90 && ev.ctrlKey === true) {
          console.log(ev);
          document.execCommand('copy');
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

All execCommand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment above, you need to check for `evt.metaKey` to catch standard macOS shortcuts, which use the same letter keys for the basic Cut/Copy/Paste/Undo as Windows (X/C/V/Z), but combined with the different command (⌘) modifier key.

It doesn't hurt in most cases if a Mac user can *also* use their control key as well as the command key for a shortcut, so the easiest solution is to check for both. Here's code from the previous answer modified to do that:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
  if (ev.keyCode === 67 && (ev.ctrlKey || ev.metaKey)) { // Copy shortcut
    console.log(ev);
    ev.preventDefault(); // block default action of browser
  }
});
```

On a Windows system, you'll probably never see a keyboard event with `metaKey` being true, because as far as I can tell, any keypress using the Win key (⊞), which theoretically maps to `metaKey`, will be intercepted by Windows before a web browser has any chance to look at it.

If you want to explore more about key events and modifier keys, I threw together a quick CodePen here for that: https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/MWmKrPM?editors=1010